# Reading integers from a file in C

Tags: c, file, scanf

I've been struggling with this for a really long time trying to figure it out, I'm guessing it's a really stupid noob mistake but I can't figure it out.

So I'm trying to read in an integer from a file and then do some operations in it, for the sake of the problem I'm just trying to output it here:

```
FILE * pFile;
int number;
pFile = fopen ("myfile.txt","r");
if (pFile!=NULL) {
fscanf(pFile, "%d", number);
fclose (pFile);
}
printf("number: %i", number);
return 0;
```

the contents of myfile.txt:

```
123
```

but when I run it it doesnt read it anything instead it says

```
RUN FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 32ms)
```

Thanks for any and all help

EDIT: I forgot to mention, it works as a string, it reads the correct number, but I can't do any operations on it, also if I set the number type to double it works but outputs some random number in the millions...

Comment: It works as a string because a string is a pointer (char*), and fscanf() requires the *address* of the location in which to store the input.

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass the address of the int variable to fscanf

```
fscanf(pFile, "%d", &number);
```

Comment: I feel like such an idiot... thanks

Comment: @user1469988 You should accept Musa's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yor need to have a pointer to number

i.e.

```
fscanf(pFile, "%d", &number);
```

And it is a good idea to check the return value from `fscanf`

You also probably need to do a flush.

i.e. After printf add the line

```
fflush(stdout);
```

Also you either need to initialise `number` or do a `return` if you are unable to open the file.

So in summary the code should look like this

```
FILE * pFile;
int number;
pFile = fopen ("myfile.txt","r");

if (NULL == pFile && 1 == fscanf(pFile, "%d", &number))
{
    printf("Number: %i", number);
    fflush(stdout);
    return 0;
}
else
{
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to pass fscanf the address of number rather than the value of number. So replace

```
fscanf(pFile, "%d", number);
```

with

```
fscanf(pFile, "%d", &number);
```

It is necessary to pass it the address of/ a pointer to number, because otherwise it cannot modify the contents of number.

Answer (score -1):

Never forget that for inputs (from keyboard/file) you need to mention the address of the variable. So you have to put `&` before the variable.

In your case:

```
fscanf(pFile, "%d", &number);
```

Also you'd better check if you reached the End-of-File or not:

```
while(fscanf(pFile, "%d", &number) != EOF){
    //do the logic
}
```

Check these manuals for more:

[Linux Programmer's Manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html)

[C library function - fscanf()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fscanf.htm)

Comment: != EOF is not a sufficient check.