# Setting a variable in a C program from a simple web page

Tags: c, gcc, raspberry-pi, html, raspbian

I have a C program running in my Raspberry Pi. I would like to create a simple web page with one button that allows me to set a boolean variable in the C program. How do I interface with the C program from a web page?

I have searched around but can't find anything useful. Any help or sample code would be great.

Comment: Why don't you post what you have done so far so we can understand what you have tried? Otherwise it will looks like a question for some homework stuff.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages now.  As it stands, this question is far too broad.  What is that C program doing?  Just waiting for inputs from the web page, or doing other stuff too?  Is the program going to be run each time the button is pushed?  If the button is pushed, does it toggle the state of the boolean, or does it always set it (to true) or reset it (to false), or what?  You also haven't specified enough what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you everyone. As a complete beginner to website hobby, I was only looking for someone to point me in the correct direction. All the answers below will give me a good start.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you, you want to set up a Raspberry Pi Web Server with CGI enabled:

- Mount a Raspbian Image: https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/
- Install Apache and enable CGI
- From your CGI C program, use `getenv("QUERY_STRING")` to catch the value sended from the html button.

This can help you in the CGI part:
https://web.ornl.gov/~ncsgroup/decode/decode_doc.html

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways of doing this. First off, if you are a beginner with setting up webpages, I would recommend you install [lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net) instead of `Apache` as it is very easy to configure.

So you would do:

```
sudo apt-get install lighttpd php-cgi
```

Then save the following as `lighttpd-local.conf`

```
################################################################################
# lighttpd-local.conf
# 
# Simple config file for lighttpd without needing to install Apache or configure
# any system-wide stuff in "/etc".
#
# Allows running Perl and PHP scripts as CGI. You may need:
#
# sudo apt-get php-cgi
#
# Just start serving the current directory by running:
#
# lighttpd -f lighttpd-local.conf
# 
# And access it in your browser (Safari, Chrome, Firefox) at:
#
# http://<IP_ADDRESS>:8000
#
################################################################################
# To see your PHP settings and configured modules, create a file in this
# directory called "phpinfo.php" which contains:
#
# <?php
# phpinfo();
# ?>
#
# And then in your browser, navigate to:
# 
# http://<IP-ADDRESS>:8000/phpinfo.php
################################################################################
# Bind to all interfaces - wired, wifi and be accessible anywhere
server.bind          = "0.0.0.0"
server.port          = 8000
server.document-root = CWD
server.errorlog          = CWD + "/lighttpd.error.log"
accesslog.filename       = CWD + "/lighttpd.access.log"
server.breakagelog       = CWD + "/lighttpd.breakage.log" 

index-file.names = ( "index.php", "index.html", "index.htm", "default.htm" )

server.modules = ("mod_cgi", "mod_accesslog")

# Ensure Perl and PHP scripts are executed rather than have their contents displayed
static-file.exclude-extensions = (".pl",".php")
cgi.assign = ( ".pl"  => "/usr/bin/perl",
               ".php" => "/usr/bin/php-cgi" )

mimetype.assign = (  
  ".css"        =>  "text/css",
  ".gif"        =>  "image/gif",
  ".htm"        =>  "text/html",
  ".html"       =>  "text/html",
  ".jpeg"       =>  "image/jpeg",
  ".jpg"        =>  "image/jpeg",
  ".js"         =>  "text/javascript",
  ".png"        =>  "image/png",
  ".txt"        =>  "text/plain"
)
```

And finally start your web server, serving the contents of the local directory:

```
lighttpd -f lighttpd-local.conf
```

---

Then you want to consider how your webpage will interact with your C program. Some possibilities are:

- via the filesystem
- via a messaging system
- via a database

---

If you want to use the filesystem, basically you make a CGI-type program that writes the variable into a file whenever the user presses a button - in the example below that file is called `"setting.txt"`. Your C program then reads the variable from that file. It could either read the file every time through its main loop, or your CGI-type program could send your C program a signal (e.g. kill -HUP ) and it could have  signal handler that re-reads the file.

So, you would save this as `index.php`:

```
<?php
// If we were POSTed, save the value in file on server for C program to see
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
   file_put_contents("setting.txt",$_POST['val']);
   // *** MARKER ***
   return;
}
?>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Simple Control</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<?php
   // PHP - executed on server before webpage is loaded
   // Get setting from previous run to pass to Javascript
   $s = file_get_contents("setting.txt");
   $s = intval($s);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Javascript - executed on client in browser

    // Put PHP variable into Javascript global
    var gblSetting=<?php echo $s; ?>;

    // This function is run when webpage is loaded
    $(document).ready(function() {

       // Display current value on webpage
       $("#idCurrent").html("Current value: " + gblSetting);

       // This function is run when button is clicked
       $('#idButton').click(function()
       {
          // Toggle the global Javascript variable
          gblSetting=1-gblSetting;

          // Send its new value to server to save for C program to see
          // See POST code at start of this file
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'index.php', 
            data:'val='+ gblSetting
          })

          // Update value on webpage
          $("#idCurrent").html("Current value: " + gblSetting);
       });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p>
<div id="idCurrent">Unknown</div>
<button id="idButton">Toggle value</button>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

and then navigate in your browser to:

```
http://<IP_ADDRESS>:8000/index.php
```

If you have got everything correct, it will look like this:

[image]

If you wanted to send a signal to your C program whenever the file changes, you would go to the line with `*** MARKER ***` and insert a call to [kill](http://php.net/manual/en/function.posix-kill.php). Then set up a signal handler in your C program that handles `SIGHUP` for example. Signal handler setup is described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_signal_handling). Here is a quick example:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <csignal>
#include <iostream>

int nSignals;

void signal_handler(int signal)
{
   std::signal(SIGHUP, signal_handler);
   std::cout << "Got signal" << std::endl;
   nSignals++;
}

int main()
{
   // Install a signal handler
   std::signal(SIGHUP, signal_handler);

   std::cout << "Send me a signal with: kill -HUP " << (int)getpid() << std::endl;

   while(nSignals<5){
      std::cout << "Received " << nSignals << " of 5 signals, sleeping..." << std::endl;
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
   }
}
```

---

If you want to use a messaging program, your C program would subscribe to a messaging system (nanomsg, zeromq, mosquitto) and your CGI-type program would send a message when the user clicks a button. You would insert that code into the above file where it says `*** MARKER ***`.

---

If you want to use a database (e.g. `sqlite` is small and easy, or `Redis` is small and easy), your C program would read its values from the database and your CGI-type program would write the value in the database when the user clicks a button. You would insert that code into the above file where it says `*** MARKER ***`. So, if you used **Redis**, that code might be something like:

```
$redis->connect('127.0.0.1'); // port 6379 by default
...
$redis->set('value', 1);
```

Then in your C program, you use [hiredis](https://github.com/redis/hiredis) and code like this to retrieve the current value:

```
redisContext *c = redisConnect("127.0.0.1", 6379);
reply = redisCommand(c,"GET value");
printf("GET value: %s\n", reply->str);
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47963630/2836621) is a link to a Redis-type of setup that could be adapted.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed example. If I have a program that looks like below. How do I use posix_kill and signal handling to toggle the variable "button" in c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

bool button = 0; //I would like to toggle this variable from a website
int main()
{
   return 0;
}

Comment: Please add any code into your original question by clicking `edit` underneath the original question - it is too hard to read in the comment area.

Comment: I don't understand. Is your comment a new question? My answer already shows you how the value in the file `setting.txt` changes when you click the button on the website. Your program should read that file when it wants the current value.

Comment: Sorry I was trying to delete that comment but it would not let me. I was trying to find an example on how to read the file "setting.txt" in c. Also I'm looking for example on the call to kill as well.

Comment: You can read a value from a file in C like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/12944846/2836621

Comment: I have added code into the answer to show you a signal handler.

Answer (score 0):

Wow! This is loaded question!

First of all you have to create a web page. Do not reinvent the wheel. You have a lot of good frameworks which can do the heavy lifting. You can use Python based [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), you can use JavaScript [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/), and so on...

Once you have a web page, you have to communicate with your program. Once again lots of choices. If I were you, I would use [nanomsg](http://nanomsg.org/) which has bindings to Python, JavaScript (Node.js), Java, C# and so on.

As for the sample code check [nanomsg for node](https://github.com/nickdesaulniers/node-nanomsg).

Comment: IMO you are overcomplicating this thing. Flask and node.js are needed only if you need server side stuff besides the "setting a bool variable in my C program", otherwise you can do perfectly well with a static page, possibly with a bit of JavaScript, and a CGI, as it was done back in the 90s; no need to get bogged down in lots of dependencies for simple stuff. For anything more complicated, I would decide for a platform (be it Python+flask or whatever) and stick to it, without introducing messaging, marshaling & co unless strictly necessary.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Thank you for you comment. You are very right, as you pointed out, for something very simple not much is needed.